# How to persist a android.net.Uri (referencing an image in Gallery) in Android

Tags: android

Through the following snippet, I get an image Uri:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_PHOTO_ALBUM);

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_PHOTO_ALBUM:
            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                displayAttachedPhoto(data.getData());
            }
            break;
```

Everything works but when I tried to persist `android.net.Uri` by:

```
String uriString = uri.toString();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("my_image", uriString);
editor.apply();
```

That's how I tried to restore:

```
String uriString = sharedPref.getString("my_image", "");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

The imageView doesn't display at all. In fact, the `Uri` object reconstructed is not the identical object. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: have you tried fetching the image before storing it to sharedpref is the uri correct ? please check that first

Comment: read the docs! https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
write time..

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("my_image", uriString);
 editor.apply();
```

getting time ..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String image = prefs.getString("my_image", null);
```

define this method..

```
  /**
```

* this method used to get camera image path.
 *
 * @param
 * @return
 */

```
public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
String res = null;
String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    res = cursor.getString(column_index);
}
cursor.close();
return res;
}
```

after that in onActivityResult method passs..

```
   Uri uri = data.getData();
    String path = getPathFromURI(uri);
```

after that path it store into sharedPreferences.

Comment: Hi. I omitted some code just for brevity. Yes. I did call `editor.apply();`.

Comment: i update my answer i think you select image path stored into sharedPreference.

Answer (score 0):

to save value in SharedPreferences ,you must use : commit or apply.

Comment: Hi. I did call that. I omitted some code just for brevity.